# Superimposed Label on the header

Tags: html, css

I have a little mistake.
[image]

As you can see ont the picture, the color picker and the checkbox are superimposed on the header. And i want it to be hidden by the header.

I don't understand why, and why the other label (text label) are hidden by the header.

For both visible element I use webkit for somes animations, maybe it can come from there.

Maybe someone has already solved the problem...

Thank you.

Comment: Learn about `z-index`es

Comment: You're going to have to provide some of the code, otherwise there's no way to know what's wrong.

Comment: It work with z-index ;) Thank you @kingkero